# ALLOWED_HOSTS and Django

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

I tried to launch a Django 1.11 project on production server. When I start the app I see the following error:

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'bla-bla-bla.bla-bla-vla.com'. You may need to add u'bla-bla-bla.bla-bla-vla.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS**

But, host `"bla-bla-bla.bla-bla-vla.com"` has been added to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py` already!

I tried to switch `DEBUG` from `False` to `True` and back. It works fine, then.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this : `ALLOWED_HOSTS=["bla-bla.com", "localhost", "127.0.0.1"]` in your setting.py file ;)

Comment: Added. No changes. I spent for this mistake about 2 hours already :(

Comment: Could you post your settings `ALLOWED_HOSTS` part ?

Comment: Yes, please:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['bla-bla.bla-bla-bla.com', "localhost", "127.0.0.1"]

I tried do something like this:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

and like this:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.bla-bla-bla.com']

no changes. I still get the same error...

Comment: Are you using Apache ?

Comment: yes. Apache 2 with Plesk and passenger module

Comment: It seems your domain is `bla-bla-bla.bla-bla-vla.com` but you've got `bla-bla.bla-bla-bla.com in your ALLOWED_HOSTS (bla-bla.bla-bla-**bla**.com instead of **bla-** bla-bla.bla-bla-**vla**.com)

Comment: This is my orthographic mistake. Sorry

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If Django says:

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: **'bla-bla-bla.bla-bla-vla.com'**. You may need
>   to add u'**bla-bla-bla.bla-bla-vla.com**' to ALLOWED_HOSTS

then you need to add **bla-bla-bla.bla-bla-vla.com**, literally (or using a dot as a wildcard) to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts)).

Then reload Apache2 (not restart, reload) to verify changes have applied.

Comment: Yep! Apache reloading helps me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

As I said in comments :

**First option :**

You have to write : `ALLOWED_HOSTS=["bla-bla.com", "localhost", "127.0.0.1"]` in settings.py file

Then, you just have to restart your server with :

```
sudo reboot
```

Or easily reload or restart apache2 service

`service apache2 reload` or `service apache2 restart`

It should work now ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is impossible. Because this is not development server, but production server. So, I can't restart physical machine.

Comment: So make `service apache2 restart` and it should take account host config

Answer (score 2):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    'localhost',
    'bla-bla',
]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue make fixed using edit settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

Then Run

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have a service like `gunicorn` between your `localhost` and your `nginx` server or `apache2` server. Remember to restart it too.

`sudo systemctl restart gunicorn`

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same error with `NGINX`. If one is developing & still testing with `port 80 only (no 443 yet)`, one may need to temporarily deactivate any `strict HTTPS` settings right from `django settings.py` itself. e.g comment:

```
# #### strict https settings
# #### UNCOMMENT at production
# SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = "same-origin"
# SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
# SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
# CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
# SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 15780000  
# SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
# SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
# SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True
# SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
# SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
#
# 
# #PREPEND_WWW = True
# #BASE_URL=["https://www.example.com"]
```

The error disappears. You can then uncomment back to `strict HTTPS` settings when the `port 443` nginx server block settings are also done.